# The subscripts are not in times new roman using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I use matplotlib for plotting and times new roman font. However, in the latest version, **the subscripts are not in Times New Roman**, while the other texts are in Times New Roman. The appearances are as follows.

[image: figure1]

For example, the code is as,

```
import matplotlib as mlp,numpy as np
mlp.rc('font',family='Times New Roman')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure();
plt.xlabel('N$_{sou}$=20',fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

and the figure is
[image: figure2]

The subscripts "sou" are not in Times New Roman, while "N" is in Times New Roman.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What code do you use to get to those images?

Comment: We would need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before we can really help you.

Comment: Plz share the code.

Comment: The code is attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TeX math mode it is standard to display mathematical expressions with a dedicated math font (usually the italic version of the font you use). Matplotlib seems to mimic this behaviour. In TeX (or LaTeX) you can get the old font back by using the [mathrm](http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/Mathrm_(LaTeX_symbol)) command, which appears to work also in matplotlib, like so:

```
import matplotlib as mlp,numpy as np
mlp.rc('font',family='Times New Roman')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,2);
axes[0].set_xlabel('N$_{sou}$=20',fontsize=20)
axes[0].set_title('normal math mode')
axes[1].set_xlabel('N$_\mathrm{sou}$=20', fontsize=20)
axes[1].set_title('using \mathrm')
plt.show()
```

[image: result of above code]

Comment: "sou" are still not in Times New Roman.

Comment: @IdeaShady Try `mathdefault` instead of `mathrm`.

Comment: It works. Thanks.